# Error with the amount of words, letters, and characters counted in a java program (in a text doc)

Tags: java, text, document

I have the intention of counting the words, letters, and characters in a text document. Sadly, the output that I have been receiving is not correct. It seems that one line is off, and because of that a few characters and words are not counted as well. Help is appreciated.

Here is the code:

```
package assignments;

import java.io.*;

public class Assignment7 {

public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
    FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(
            "C:/Users/Shashu/Desktop/Workspace/sample.txt");
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(file));
    int i;
    int countw = 0, countl = 0, countc = 0;
    do {
        i = br.read();
        if ((char) i == (' ')) { 
            countw++;
        }
        if ((char) i == ('\n')) { 
            countw++; 
            countl++;
        } 
        if (i != -1) {
            countc++; 
        }

    } while (i != -1);

    System.out.println("Number of words " + countw);
    System.out.println("Number of lines " + countl); 
    System.out.println("Number of characters " + countc);
}
}
```

And here is the text document:

```
hi my name is shashu
hello
hello
hello
```

And here is the output:

```
Number of words 7
Number of lines 4
Number of characters 41
```

All help and criticism is appreciated! Thanks in advance.
EDIT: Okay, I fixed that issue, thank you everyone. However, now how would I go about making it so I could choose the text file in the command prompt?

For example:

java Assignment7 sample.txt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
    FileInputStream file = null;
    BufferedReader br = null;
    try {
        file = new FileInputStream(
                "C:/Users/Shashu/Desktop/Workspace/sample.txt");
        br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(file));

        int countw = 0, countl = 0, countc = 0;
        String line = null;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            countl++;
            String[] words = line.split(" ");
            for (String word : words) {
                word = word.trim();
                if (word.length() == 0) {
                    continue;
                }
                countw++;
                countc += word.length();
            }

        }
        System.out.println("Number of words " + countw);
        System.out.println("Number of lines " + countl);
        System.out.println("Number of characters " + countc);
    } finally {
        if (file != null) {
            file.close();
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your text document does not have a new line character (actually two characters in Windows) at the end so the last word is not counted.